# Defining a DataTemplate for a KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, wpf, key-value, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am attempting to specify a `KeyValuePair<int,MyClass>` as the data type for a DataTemplate in WPF.  The KeyValuePair is from an `ObservableDictionary` object (I am using [Dr WPF's implementation](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/) if it is relevant.

Using [How to reference a generic type in the DataType attribute of a HierarchicalDataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706123/how-to-reference-a-generic-type-in-the-datatype-attribute-of-a-hierarchicaldatat), I was able to get something close, however, I am getting a compiler error.

I need to be able to define the HierarchicalDataTemplate for the KeyValuePair so I can create another leaf in the TreeView below it containing a collection that is part of the Value object of the Dictionary.

The XAML is simply:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{local:GenericKeyValuePairType  
                                     KeyType=sys:Int32, 
                                     ValueType=local:MyClass}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.MyList}" />
```

And GenericKeyValuePairType is a MarkupExtension

```
public class GenericKeyValuePairType : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type KeyType { get; set; }
    public Type ValueType { get; set; }


    public GenericKeyValuePairType() { }
    public GenericKeyValuePairType(Type keyType, Type valueType)
    {
        KeyType = keyType;
        ValueType = valueType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return typeof(KeyValuePair<,>).MakeGenericType(this.KeyType, this.ValueType);
    }
}
```

When I do this, Visual Studio indicates that this is not valid.  The specific error is:

> A key for a dictionary cannot be of type 'TreeViewBindingTest.GenericKeyValuePairType'. Only String, TypeExtension, and StaticExtension are supported.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?  If so, is there a better approach?

Comment: in the thread you linked to there is an example of xaml for a dictionary.  any reason why you cannot use that implementation? I might be misinterpreting what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Default I am using it, but I need to define a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the KeyValuePairs within that dictionary as the Value object has another collection that will be another leaf in the `TreeView`.  So I need to be able to define the structure below it.  I tried hooking to the `Values` property, which does work, but because the `Values` collection is not observable, any changes to the Dictionary do not get shown in the `TreeView`

Comment: In your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` you are binding `MyList` to `ItemsSource`. But the `KeyValuePair` hasn't the `MyList` property. Could `MyClass` be the source of the template?

Comment: @IlVic should be Value.MyList. A typo when creating my example.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using `KeyValuePair` as DataContext of a TreeViewItem is not correct. KeyValuePair is sealed, so you can't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
Moreover you can't use your `GenericKeyValuePairType` extension since the compiler believe that you want to use that object as DataType (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897584/specifying-datatemplate-datatype-with-a-custom-type-extension) for more info).

Indeed your model is `MyClass` object (you confirmed that `MyList` property belongs to it). In this case your DataTemplate will be:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" />
```

I believe it is conceptually more correct.