# Generic type in DataType of WPF's DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider a public class `LogItem` and a derived generic class `LogItem<T>` as shown below. After some wasted time searching for the correct syntax to specify the generic type in XAML, the editor was finally happy. Yet I got the error below trying to build the project. I am using VS 2017 Preview but I am guessing VS 2017 would barf just the same. If I omit the `(system:Int32)` part, everything goes as planned. I am using NET 4.6.2.

> error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'modules:LogItem(system:Int32)'.
>   Note that type names are case sensitive.

```
namespace App.Modules
{
    public class LogItem
    {
        public string Info { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogItem<T> : LogItem
    {
        public T Content { get; set; }
    }
}

    xmlns:modules="clr-namespace:App.Modules"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type modules:LogItem(system:Int32)}">
```

Comment: Can we see your `xmlns` declarations? Also, which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @laptou Sure. I've updated the question.

Comment: Is your XAML in the same assembly as the type you are trying to reference?

Comment: Very much so. Not just that but also in the very same namespace.

Comment: Does it work if you write ``modules:LogItem`1`` instead?

Comment: The app builds but that does not produce the desired result, does it? Suppose I want to have two templates based on different generic params.

Comment: Not sure if this syntax is valid for `x:Type`. I only found mention of it in the `x:TypeArguments` documentation.

Comment: Not sure either. I found reference to it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711368/275449

Comment: Which also does not compile.

Comment: Yeah. And when I try to write my own custom `MarkupExtension`, I get a nasty surprise with `error MC3012: A key for a dictionary cannot be of type ... Only String, TypeExtension, and StaticExtension...`

Comment: Crazy as it seems but I might have to go with this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360065/275449